# Get a specific entity in inheritance model with with Grails (GORM)

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, grails, grails-orm

We needed to build a several similar entities with small differences between them, and we decided to get with an inheritance available in GORM.
Our domain classes look something like this:

```
class Idea extends AuditableEntity {

    Project project
    User user

    String content

    static mapping = {
        content type: 'text'

        autoTimestamp true
    }

    static constraints = {
        content nullable: false, blank: false
    }

}
```

and one of the children:

```
class FpIdea extends Idea {

    FortyPrinciplesApplication fpApplication
    Principle principle

    static mapping = {
        importFrom Idea

        discriminator 'fp_idea'

        table 'fp_idea'
    }

    static constraints = {
        importFrom Idea

        fpApplication nullable: false
        principle nullable: false
    }

}
```

Now, everything works as expected, and we can easily pull the correct object type if we know what the type suppose to be.
However, is there a way, to get an idea object simply by id (without knowing the type ahead of type) and still get it in the correct type?

If we make the request through `Idea`, then we get an `Idea` object with `expandoMetaclass`. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it already does it out of the box.
So, if I try to get an object like so:

```
Idea.findByIdAndProjectAndUser(id, project, user)
```

It provides the correct object type. But, the information in debugger misleading.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can remove discriminator customization.

> discriminator 'fp_idea'

in this case Grails will use default discriminator(by default class column with full class name) 
To check type you can use something like:

```
Idea.get(1L).class == FpIdea
```

2. Or you can use different tables for each subclass:

> ```
> static mapping = {
>         tablePerHierarchy false
>     }
> ```

in parent domain